# bxslider - custom controls outside the slider

Tags: controls, bxslider

Iam new to css and html5. 
I`m using bxslider and would like to have controls (arrow nav) outside the slider div. I made it according to http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors but I do not like it.
How to replace "onward" with an arrow image (jpg)? 
How can I move my arrow image to the edge of the slider? I don't want it in the center but aside the slider.

http://www.pulik.edl.pl/WWWMG/foto.html

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the controls of the own bxslider and change its css?
Then with left/right you can work around to make the controls to be on the edge of the slider.

Else, if you really want to use the custom controls, make a container around the controls and the slider. Then you can easily do the trick, if the container was made properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to use the controls of the bxslider, I was trying to change the numbers in css but it doesn`t work (the arrow is coming always to the border of the slide - I want it to be outside the slider). Would you like to tell me which point of /* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */in CSS should I change to get the controls outside the slider?

Comment: I found it ! :) Thanks for your precious tip!

Comment: Sorry for not answering faster, but I was without computer.
Glad you find the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To move the direction controls outside of the content, you'll need to override the bxslider css in your own css file:

```
.bx-prev {
    margin-left: -70px;
}

.bx-next {
    margin-right: -70px;
}
```

This might cause a further issue where the controls are outside ALL of your content and not even visible.  In that case you should wrap the whole slider control inside another div that has left and right padding.